# In Azure Functions app, how can we execute the How can i run this command "sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss"

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

Command:

```
"sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss"
```

Functions app : Linux, python

We install other modules using requirements.txt, But how can i run the above command in functions app.

Please guide/help on this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libasound2 package cannot be installed in general function apps. Rather go for docker container function apps, where this package can be installed in Dockerfile using the below command,

```
RUN YES | sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss
```

Comment: Can someone verify this answer as per current state of Azure Functions. Or a link to documentation can also be helpful.